# How can I install ebaysdk-python library?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, python

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 on a server and trying to install [this library](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python)) but am having trouble as I'm quite new to Ubuntu and the instruction raise errors.

The installation instructions from the project give the commands:

```
sudo easy_install ebaysdk
```

or

```
sudo easy_install https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/archive/master.zip
```

Both of which give the error:

```
sudo: easy_install: command not found
```

I haven't been able to `pip install` it either because it isn't available in Ubuntu packages.

Is there another simple way to install this python package?

Many thanks

Edit:
I've not been able to get easy_install to work by following answers in other posts. Is there another way to install from a url?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the library directly by pulling it from GitHub

```
git clone https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/
```

Then go into the folder and install it by typing

```
cd ebaysdk-python && python ./setup.py install
```